# Postman Accesstoken Automatic refresh issue

Tags: javascript, api, postman, access-token, postman-pre-request-script

I'm a newbie in postman. I'm trying to automate the process of refreshing Access token using pre-request script of postman as mentioned in the below document

[Click here](https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/automatically-generate-new-oauth2-tokens-when-using-postman)

Pre-request Code:

```
     let tokenUrl = 'https://oauth.brightcove.com/v4/access_token';
     let clientId = '-----------------------------------------';
      let clientSecret ='---------------------------------------';
     let getTokenRequest = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: tokenUrl,
    auth: {
    type: "basic",
    basic: [
        { key: "username", value: clientId },
        { key: "password", value: clientSecret }
    ]
},
body: {
    mode: 'urlencoded',
    urlencoded: [
        { key: 'grant_type', value: 'client_credentials' }
    ]
}
};

  pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
let jsonResponse = response.json(),
    newAccessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;

console.log({ err, jsonResponse, newAccessToken })

pm.environment.set('accessToken', newAccessToken);
pm.variables.set('accessToken', newAccessToken);
 });
```

While running the api, postman console shows the following error

{{err: null, jsonResponse: {…}, newAccessToken: undefined}
err: null
jsonResponse: {…}
error: "invalid_client"
error_description: "The "client_id" parameter is missing, does not name a client registration that is applicable for the requested call, or is not properly authenticated."
newAccessToken: undefined

[Access Token API Documentation](https://support.brightcove.com/getting-access-tokens)

Stuck with this error for almost 4-5 hrs. 
 Can anyone tell me what's the issue here?

Comment: seems like your credentials are incorrect?

Comment: @C2H50H Nope there is no issues with the credentials, I have cross checked ,got the access token from postman authorization tab using the same credentials

Comment: Assuming you have tried creating a new token as well?

Comment: yupp i have tried creating a new token